# How to prevent the scroll from jumping to the top of the web page on Nuxt3 reload

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I have a problem with scrollBehavior in Nuxt.js 3. When I refresh the page (when static content is served), the scroll jumps abruptly to the top of the page. However, after serving the static content, there is an automatic scroll to the previous position (the position from which the refresh was triggered), which creates an unpleasant "jumping" effect on the website.

How can I prevent the scroll from returning to the top of the document when reloading Nuxt3 and keep  the scroll at the same position?

Comment: Do you have a reproduction on your issue? In your case, it is harder for us to help without  the reproduction. You can use stackblitz or codesanbox

Comment: I think that "pages" directory is creating such effect...
You can check reproduction of my code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-cgquz4?file=pages%2Findex.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, this issue can be fix by disabling the `SSR` mode in the `nuxt.config`.

But, there is a temporary solution in order for it to work on `SSR`.

You need to add these lines of codes, you can add this inside the nuxt pages or in the layout.

```js
onMounted(() => {
    if (process.client && window) {
        window.history.scrollRestoration = 'auto';
    }
})
```

Ensure to add smooth scrolling CSS

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Following that codes should fix your issue.

Tested and it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really helped me, I was struggling with this issue for two days.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. You can mark it as an answer by clicking the check icon. Thanks!